# Custom SimpleListFilter Subclass for DjangoAdmin

Tags: python, django

Following Django's documentation I need a SimpleListFilter subclass very similar as the one described [there](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.list_filter):

```
from datetime import date

from django.utils.translation import ugettext_lazy as _
from django.contrib.admin import SimpleListFilter

class DecadeBornListFilter(SimpleListFilter):
    # Human-readable title which will be displayed in the
    # right admin sidebar just above the filter options.
    title = _('decade born')

    # Parameter for the filter that will be used in the URL query.
    parameter_name = 'decade'

    def lookups(self, request, model_admin):
        """
        Returns a list of tuples. The first element in each
        tuple is the coded value for the option that will
        appear in the URL query. The second element is the
        human-readable name for the option that will appear
        in the right sidebar.
        """
        return (
            ('80s', _('in the eighties')),
            ('90s', _('in the nineties')),
        )

    def queryset(self, request, queryset):
        """
        Returns the filtered queryset based on the value
        provided in the query string and retrievable via
        `self.value()`.
        """
        # Compare the requested value (either '80s' or 'other')
        # to decide how to filter the queryset.
        if self.value() == '80s':
            return queryset.filter(birthday__gte=date(1980, 1, 1),
                                    birthday__lte=date(1989, 12, 31))
        if self.value() == '90s':
            return queryset.filter(birthday__gte=date(1990, 1, 1),
                                    birthday__lte=date(1999, 12, 31))

class PersonAdmin(ModelAdmin):
    list_filter = (DecadeBornListFilter,)
```

The only change I need to do is in the lookups method, instead of listing decades such as 80's or 90's i would like show widgets to allow to choose a month and a year, for example JAN, 2000.

In the best scenario i would like to do that using two dropdown menus, one for year and another for month. Another alternative would be re-using a Date Range such as [DateRangeFilter](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/django-daterange-filter), which i tried but I wasn't able to create a new filter class inheriting DateRangeFilter or using DateRangeFilter in the new filter class' lookups method.

I am using Django 1.7.8, any help or hint will be very appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need two list_filters, one for the maximal date and one for the minimum date. Query your entries for all distinct years. Something like this:

```
class MaxDateListFilter(SimpleListFilter):
    title = _('maximum date')
    parameter_name = 'max_date'

    def lookups(self, request, model_admin):
        return [(str(year.year), year.year) \
                 for year in Entry.objects.dates('pub_date', 'year')]

    def queryset(self, request, queryset):
        return queryset.filter(pub_date__year__lte=self.value())
```

Note: Untested code.

This will work for small ranges. But can be unpractical with bigger datasets.

An alternative is to provide your own [ModelAdmin.get_search_results](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.get_search_results) and make it accept some date search queries. Once you have that, you need to render your own ModelAdmin.changelist_view. Add a form to the context and customise the change list template to render this form. Submitting the form should produce the correct search GET request.